# Кастомный шрифт не хочет отображаться в окне

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit, qfont, qfontdatabase

Файла ресурсов нет и делать его не желательно, так как все нужные шрифты и иконки лежат в папке проекта.

Пытаюсь добавить шрифт таким кодом:

```
QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(":/fonts/AmaticSC-Regular.ttf")
fontSegoeui = QFontDatabase.font("Amatic SC", "Regular", 14)
```

Шрифт должен отображаться в QTextEdit (если это имеет какого значение).
При запуске выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> TypeError: font(self, str, str, int): 
> first argument of unbound method must have type 'QFontDatabase'

Свойства шрифта:

[image: Скриншот]

Через такое добавление тоже не работает (но ошибку не выдаёт, а просто игнорирует шрифт):

```
fontArial = QFont('fonts/AmaticSC-Regular.ttf', 18, 75)
```

Подскажите на основе любого шрифта как его можно добавить без файла ресурсов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   
w = QWidget()
w.setWindowTitle("Roboto Fonts")

fid = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('D:/_Qt/__Qt/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf')

layout = QGridLayout(w)                
layout.addWidget(QTextEdit('Hello World', font=QFont('RobotoBold', 22)))                       

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С абсолютным путём работает, спасибо! Если у кого-нибудь возникнет такая же проблема, смотрите модуль os.getcwd(). Но сейчас у меня сработал относительный путь, хотя я уже пробовал добавлять шрифт в базу, а потом вызывать его через QFont. Видимо мои пробы были с ошибкой, после чего я пошёл во все тяжкие и код стал неправильным ещё больше.

Comment: @PandaStock пожалуйста.